# How to add links to WooCommerce products titles

Tags: php, wordpress

I just installed a Wordpress template with integrated WooCommerce. Everything is ok but the titles of the single products are simple text and i would like to convert them in links to the products as in the preview image.

Can somebody help me to fix this? Thanks!!
http://www.mvdev.it/succhi/

```
if ( !function_exists( 'sunnyjar_woocommerce_open_thumb_wrapper' ) ) {
    //Handler of add_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'sunnyjar_woocommerce_open_thumb_wrapper', 9 );
    //Handler of add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'sunnyjar_woocommerce_open_thumb_wrapper', 9 );
    function sunnyjar_woocommerce_open_thumb_wrapper($cat='') {
        sunnyjar_storage_set('in_product_item', true);
        ?>
        <div class="post_item_wrap">
            <div class="post_featured">
                <div class="post_thumb">
                    <a class="hover_icon hover_icon_link" href="<?php echo esc_url(is_object($cat) ? get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') : get_permalink()); ?>">
        <?php
    }
}


if ( !function_exists( 'sunnyjar_woocommerce_open_item_wrapper' ) ) {
    //Handler of add_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'sunnyjar_woocommerce_open_item_wrapper', 20 );
    //Handler of add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'sunnyjar_woocommerce_open_item_wrapper', 20 );
    function sunnyjar_woocommerce_open_item_wrapper($cat='') {
        ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_content"> 
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: add your code here so we can help you

Comment: I edited my post with a copy/paste of the code....I guess these are the lines to change. Thanks!!